# Is it possible to get milliseconds from Python 3's native time library?

Tags: python-3.x

I have been trying to find a nice way to format a timestamp of the current date & time with milliseconds using Python 3's native `time` library.
However there's no directive for milliseconds in the standard documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime.
There's undocumented directives though, like `%s` which will give the unix timestamp. Is there any other directives like this?

Code example:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %s')
'2017-08-28 09:27:04 1503912424'
```

Ideally I would just want to change the trailing `%s` to some directive for milliseconds.

I'm using Python 3.x.
I'm fully aware that it's quite simple to get milliseconds using the native `datetime` library, however I'm looking for a solution using the native `time` library solely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insist on using `time` only:

```
miliSeconds = time.time()%1*1000
```

`time()` returns accurately the time since the epoch. Since you already have the the date up to a second, you don't really care this is a time delta, since the remaining fraction is what you need to add anyway to what you have already to get the accurate date. `%1` retrieves the fraction and then I convert the numbers to millisecond by multiplying by `1000`.

**note**

> Note that even though the time is always returned as a floating point
>   number, not all systems provide time with a better precision than 1
>   second. While this function normally returns non-decreasing values, it
>   can return a lower value than a previous call if the system clock has
>   been set back between the two calls.

Taken from https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time. But this means there is no way to do what you want. You may be able to do something more robust with `process_time`, but that would have to be elaborate.